# eosforumdapp mongodb : unsupported_abi_version_exception: ABI has an unsupported version

Tags: nodeos, abi, database

Syncing my node, everything works fine. I get a warning though when processing transactions from eosforumdapp and eosforumcpp

```
info  2018-10-20T09:07:14.286 thread-1  mongo_db_plugin.cpp:481       consume_blocks       ] process_accepted_block,       time per: 1712, size: 465, time: 796163
warn  2018-10-20T09:07:15.226 thread-1  mongo_db_plugin.cpp:651       get_abi_serializer   ] 3015016 unsupported_abi_version_exception: ABI has an unsupported version
ABI has an unsupported version
    {}
    thread-1  abi_serializer.cpp:109 set_abi
warn  2018-10-20T09:07:15.226 thread-1  mongo_db_plugin.cpp:651       get_abi_serializer   ] n: eosforumdapp
info  2018-10-20T09:07:17.659 thread-1  mongo_db_plugin.cpp:456       consume_blocks       ] process_applied_transaction,  time per: 1456, size: 2073, time: 3019243
info  2018-10-20T09:07:17.821 thread-1  mongo_db_plugin.cpp:934       _process_accepted_bl ] block_num: 17314000

warn  2018-10-20T09:09:14.425 thread-1  mongo_db_plugin.cpp:651       get_abi_serializer   ] n: eosforumrcpp
warn  2018-10-20T09:09:15.961 thread-1  mongo_db_plugin.cpp:651       get_abi_serializer   ] 3015016 unsupported_abi_version_exception: ABI has an unsupported version
ABI has an unsupported version
    {}
    thread-1  abi_serializer.cpp:109 set_abi
warn  2018-10-20T09:09:15.961 thread-1  mongo_db_plugin.cpp:651       get_abi_serializer   ] n: eosforumdapp
info  2018-10-20T09:09:17.233 thread-1  mongo_db_plugin.cpp:456       consume_blocks       ] process_applied_transaction,  time per: 1483, size: 2073, time: 3074877
```

Running a non-producing node, non Docker. Latest eos version: 1.4.1
Relevant parts of my config.ini:

```
bnet-follow-irreversible = 0
bnet-no-trx = false
read-mode = read-only
validation-mode = light
mongodb-uri = mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/EOS
mongodb-queue-size = 2048
mongodb-abi-cache-size = 2048
mongodb-block-start = 1
mongodb-store-blocks = 0
mongodb-store-transactions = 0
mongodb-store-transaction-traces = 0
mongodb-store-action-traces = 1
mongodb-filter-on = *
mongodb-filter-out = eosio:onblock:
mongodb-filter-out = gu2tembqgage::
mongodb-filter-out = blocktwitter::

wasm-runtime = wabt
p2p-max-nodes-per-host = 1
http-validate-host = false
https-client-validate-peers = 1
abi-serializer-max-time-ms = 10000
chain-state-db-size-mb = 32000
reversible-blocks-db-size-mb = 340
contracts-console = false
allowed-connection = any
max-clients = 100
network-version-match = 0
sync-fetch-span = 500
connection-cleanup-period = 30
max-implicit-request = 1500

access-control-allow-origin = *
access-control-allow-headers = *
access-control-allow-credentials = false
verbose-http-errors = true

plugin = eosio::chain_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::bnet_plugin
plugin = eosio::mongo_db_plugin
plugin = eosio::http_plugin
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps when you were synching, at that moment in time, `eosforumrcpp` had an invalid ABI version?

Right now, it seems like their versioning is fine:

```
$ cleos get abi eosforumrcpp
{                                 
  "version": "eosio::abi/1.0",
  ...
}
```

This should pass the check in [`abi_serializer.cpp`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/2232802dee4be1a3f6ca436edad64af3c45d7029/libraries/chain/abi_serializer.cpp#L109):

```
EOS_ASSERT(starts_with(abi.version, "eosio::abi/1."), unsupported_abi_version_exception, "ABI has an unsupported version");
```